# how to define a constraint for column to have alphanumeric values in oracle?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, constraints, alphanumeric

I need to create a table which has a column. the entries should be alphanumeric.
how can i define a constraint for this situation
I tried using,

```
create table bankAccount  
(  
accNo varchar2(15) check (accNo like '%[A-Za-Z0-9]%')  
);
```

but during input no data is stored and no entries are created.

Comment: Is null ok as well? If yes, then you'd need to add `or accNo is null` as `regexp_like(accNo,^[A-Z...]*$)`(zero or more quantifier) covers no empty/null values in oracle

Answer (score 4):

You would use `REGEXP_LIKE()` but if all the characters have to be alphanumeric then you need start and end anchors:

```
CREATE TABLE bankaccount
( accno VARCHAR2(15) CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE(accno, '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$') ) );
```

(Note that you can also use the `[[:alnum:]]` POSIX character class instead of `[A-Za-z0-9]`.)

If you want the account numbers to be exactly 15 characters, then you might want something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE bankaccount
( accno VARCHAR2(15) CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE(accno, '^[A-Za-z0-9]{15}$') ) );
```

And if you want only uppercase letters:

```
CREATE TABLE bankaccount
( accno VARCHAR2(15) CHECK ( REGEXP_LIKE(accno, '^[A-Z0-9]+$') ) );
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: . . If the OP wanted `accno` to be exactly 15 characters, then the best approach is to declare it as `CHAR(15)`.

Comment: Actually a `VARCHAR2(15)` column is stored the same as a `CHAR(15)` in Oracle so there is no advantage to using the latter (see https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:123212348063 ), but in any case I can't see a good reason not to mention the check for exact length as an option.

Comment: . . .You are misunderstanding the "asktom" answer.  The Oracle documentation also directly contradicts your comment (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1822).

Comment: No ... I don't mean that the values are stored the same, I mean that the underlying mechanics are the same. Using CHAR in Oracle gains nothing.

Comment: . . It affects how much space is occupied by the value.  If the OP knows that the value has 15 characters, then the appropriate type is `CHAR(15)`, not `VARCHAR()`/`VARCHAR2()`.

Comment: + CHAR(15) always returns a 15 char long value, with training spaces if a shorter value was inserted. And spaces aren't covered in the current regexp

Comment: A 15-character value stored in a CHAR(15) column does not take up less space than a similar value stored in a VARCHAR2(15) column in Oracle. Maybe that's not the case in other RDBMSs. But in any case your objection is completely irrelevant to the question posed by the OP

Answer (score 1):

You would use `regexp_like()`:

```
accNo varchar2(15) check (regexp_like(accNo, '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'))
```

Comment: This would validate `"&£$%*^%$A$$&*` ([SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59563/2)) which is not an alphanumeric value; you need to anchor the regular expression to the start and end of the string using `^` and `$` (as per David Faber's answer). Also, you have a misstyped the regular expression as `a-Z` (lowercase-Uppercase) is not a valid regular expression range.

Comment: @MT0 . . . The issue is fixed.